# How to set variable for 3 arguments taken in using sys.arg

Tags: python, variables, arguments

This is where the variables are defined, now its supposed to take in as an argument a (directory,filename,slicesize) but when I plug it in it gives me an error of "list index out of range", is there something wrong within this piece of code? Or am I calling it incorrectly?

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    dirname = sys.argv[1]
    filename = sys.argv[2]
    slicesize = int(sys.argv[3])
    sort_big_text_file(dirname,filename,slicesize)




sort_big_text_file('C:/Python/','dotcom_data.txt', 100000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with what I was doing is that I was calling the function when it executed at the end, and that should've came before that last functions, what I believe you would call the main. So instead of what I did, like this:

```
sort_big_text_file('C:/Python/','com_data.txt', 100000)

if __name__=="__main__":
    dirname = sys.argv[1]
    filename = sys.argv[2]
    slicesize = int(sys.argv[3])
    sort_big_text_file(dirname,filename,slicesize)
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays normally start at index 0. Did you mean to use

```
if __name__=="__main__":
  dirname = sys.argv[0]
  filename = sys.argv[1]
  slicesize = int(sys.argv[2])
  sort_big_text_file(dirname,filename,slicesize)
```

Do you have 3 arguments? you can check that using

```
if len(sys.argv) < 3:
  sys.stderr.write('error: not enough arguments')
```

Comment: The first item in `argv` is the name used to call the executed script/program.

Comment: I tried starting from index zero, but I still get the same error "List not in index range", and the functions does take three arguments I looked over it and everything seems fine, just unsure why I get this error]

Comment: It's line 86 which ends up being like line 2 here, but I will post an answer with why it was that my program wasn't running, and thank you for your helpful, helped me figure it out :)!

Comment: @JAB unless phyton is started with the `-c` option to execute commands from the command line. Then `argv[0]` would be the `-c` but probably that's not the case here